# Why does ssh clone from gitlab repo need password from WSL but not Linux-native PC?

Tags: ssh, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gitlab

From a Linux-native desktop, I am able to clone a project from our gitlab repo like this:

```
git clone git@git.company.com:namespace/project.git
```

No problem with the above: specifically, I'm not asked for the `git@git.company.com` password.

I've needed to switch to Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux (WSL); when I try the same project cloning, I *am* prompted for the `git@git.company.com` password, which I don't have.

**Question: Why am I prompted for the password in one environment but not the other?**

---

What I've tried:
1. Since I had ssh keys in the Linux-native environment, I created them in WSL:

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:16ba121a04d5ad3b885f09af5+c6c08b68766ce43d9 user@JFNM38J2
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

2. Because of an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432899/gitlab-prompts-for-git-password-when-cloning-a-git-repository), I started sshd in WSL:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
                                                       [ OK ]
```

3. I've tried comparing the outputs of `ssh -vT git@git.company.com` in the two environments.
   What stands out is that in the Linux-native environment, there is a "`Server accepts key...`" comment that is absent in the WSL environment. But I don't really understand why, or, more importantly, what else I can do to set up the WSL environment so that it, like the Linux-native environment, skips the `git@git.company.com` password.

```
$ # This is the Linux-native environment
$ uname -a
Linux linuxbox 5.4.8-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 6 16:44:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ssh -vT git@git.company.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d FIPS  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to git.company.com [10.138.1.176] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to git.company.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+a3ohHfIsc5Bi99RHkwQQTZfMO0IdC5vj3Dxk6XpR9J
debug1: Host 'git.company.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:59
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Cf6Ann313zL2As5qABJe85JKJV3L3pGERP+VRCYIaAg agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Cf6Ann313zL2As5qABJe85JKJV3L3pGERP+VRCYIaAg agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Cf6Ann313zL2As5qABJe85JKJV3L3pGERP+VRCYIaAg agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to git.company.com ([10.138.1.176]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:1121: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Remote: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:1121: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to GitLab, @user!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2828, received 2880 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 43777.7, received 44582.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

.

```
$ # This is the WSL environment
$ uname -a
Linux windowsbox 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ssh -vT git@git.company.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.company.com [199.21.163.250] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to git.company.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+a3ohHfIsc5Bi99RHkwQQTZfMO0IdC5vj3Dxk6XpR9J
debug1: Host 'git.company.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nis
tp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EfQKfAR2alQK13JaqZ8AVMP7B+hqDEC9CGsOfqOHhL0 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@git.company.com's password:
```

**Can anyone explain what's going on in these two environments, and why one can clone from `git@git.company.com:namespace/project.git` without user-input password while the other cannot?**

Comment: First forget about step 2. Starting an ssh server in your pc won't solve the problem. Second I see that instead of copying the keys from the Linux environment you created new ones. Your problem is that the configuration in both environments is not the same. Also check if you are not using the git installed on Windows instead WSL one

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez - By "copying the keys from the Linux environment" does that mean `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` ? Do you mean I should literally copy those two files from the Linux environment to the WSL environment? I must confess a weak understanding of most things cryptography related, so please forgive the rudimentary questions trying to understand your suggestion.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez - well, I tried copying those two files over from the Linux PC to WSL, and that actually seems to have made the subsequent `ssh -vT` work! I'm quite curious what's going on - would be grateful if you have an explanation for what happened here.

Answer (score 1):

In your Linux desktop, you are connecting using certificates instead of passwords. Probably months ago you configured your access to GitLab following the instructions there (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) generating a keypair with ssh-gen and then you copied the public key on the GitLab website. You can check this doing a `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and compare this with a field called SSH Key in your GitLab profile's security settings.

Now in the new environment, you generated a new key pair that didn't match with the one in GitLab settings thus it asked for the password. What I suggested in the comments was to copy the keypair usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your WSL environment. This is a common behavior recommended especially if you switch frequently between WSL and Windows tools. In this case, you can copy the credentials to the .ssh folder in your Windows home. You could also create a new key and add it to GitLab.

Hope it helps

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your Git server is likely a GitLab instance, which uses the default OpenSSH service for SSH operations.  When you push to the instance, you need to have an SSH key available, but because OpenSSH is configured for password support, if you don't have a valid SSH key, then you'll be prompted for a password.

However, because this is a service account, there is really no valid password for that account (the password hash is set to an invalid value that matches no valid hash), and you won't be able to log in if you don't have a key.  Other hosting platforms, such as GitHub, don't use the system OpenSSH, and instead will simply reject any connection that doesn't provide a valid public key.

Since the SSH key in one environment (WSL) was different and unknown to the server, the server rejected it and fell back to the next authentication method.  You could just have added the existing key (the one in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to your user account in GitLab and then you'd have been able to access the server.